# How to scrape data from web site that is made with Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I want to scrape data from web site.
I can scrape data from normal html web site by using `selenium-webdriver` and `phantomjs`.

But it is impossible get data from Java Applet.

How can I get data from Java Applet application?

Comment: A Java applet will use AWT to display its UI. There is no HTML to scrape.  You might be able to find a way to capture the canvas and analyze it to find UI elements, but that's likely to be extremely difficult.

Comment: I agree that this will likely be nigh impossible.

Comment: *"I want to scrape data from web site."*  The web is a big place.  Narrow it down with an URL for the site.